# Automatically adding page breaks into long array environments

Tags: spacing, arrays

I have been generating a lot of data for a project and I wrote in TeX commands (via print statements) so that I get rows upon rows of data entries that look like

```
 a_{1} & a_{2} & a_{3} \\
```

This allows me to readily copy and paste over the data into an array environment, but when I typeset the data text runs to the bottom of the page and cuts part of it off, thereby not displaying all of it. I using the array environment and my TeX codes looks something like

```
\[
  \begin{array}{c c c}
    a_{1} & a_{2} & a_{3} \\
    a_{6} & a_{7} & a_{8} \\
    (many more such entries)
  \end{array}
\]
```

Comment: Consider to use `longtable` instead equation environment with `array`. Columns in this table of it can be set in math mode with  `>{$} c <{$}`.

Answer (score 5):

You can make a `longtable` environment look very much like an `array` environment. The `longtable` environment provides for automatic page breaking, and you can give it a `\caption`, if need be.

If it's not possible to tell which of the following two arrays was created with `longtable` and which was created with `array`, that's by design. :-)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,longtable}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{$}c<{$}}  % automatic math mode, centered
\setlength\tabcolsep{5pt}     % match value of \arraycolsep 
\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{CCC}
    a_{1} & a_{2} & a_{3} \\
    a_{6} & a_{7} & a_{8} \\
    \multicolumn{3}{l}{and so on}\\
\end{longtable}

\[
  \begin{array}{c c c}
    a_{1} & a_{2} & a_{3} \\
    a_{6} & a_{7} & a_{8} \\
    \multicolumn{3}{l}{$and so on$}\\
  \end{array}
\]

\end{document}
```